# Multi-user remote desktop using vnc4server

Tags: vnc

I have setup vnc4server on the main PC using [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_5089245_install-vnc-server-ubuntu.html) and I only see this:

[Image Removed]

What is the problem? Does it matter if the client I'm connecting from uses different DE than the main PC?

Comment: Which vnc viewer are you using? It looks like your screenshot is from your vnc viewer and is setting parameters for its behavior. I followed the HowTo you indicated and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your intended purpose is for setting this up. Are you trying to set up to allow multiple simultaneous vnc logins to your system? I don't think the way this HowTo sets up the server will provide a satisfactory multi-user server since it just sets up an additional desktop for the logged in user that can be accessed over the network. If you log out, it will kill the additional vnc desktop as well.

Comment: There was an error on my end. And yes, I'm trying to setup multiple simultaneous logins to different users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not matter which desktop environment your client and server are running. Vnc is designed to allow controlling any vnc server from any vnc client regardless of which operating system is running on either.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to install anything to enable VNC sharing. Just go to System>Preferences>Remote Desktop and enable it.